TV show consisting of unrelated episodes mainly about science fiction from the early 2000s I think
I only saw about 6 episodes on TV, it usually ran late at night in my country, but I can only remember the plot of one episode. In this episode the structure was like a detective movie, there were two male protagonists (maybe scientists) investigating strange events on an university campus that seemed to indicate the existence of an invisible person. I remember one scene in which one of the protagonists sees a picture of a flying hummingbird whose wings move so fast that they become invisible and he theorized that the person they were looking for somehow exists in a state of high speed and that's why nobody can see him. At the end of the episode the two protagonists are able to enter this state and the world around them freezes as they perceive it at a much faster rate. Finally they are able to find the person they were looking for. They find him to be very old, and he tells them that aging is a side effect of this high speed state. That's about all I can remember, please help me find this show and specifically this episode. 

sadly, no. the sow itself is not about invisibility. it was just the plot of this one episode

What country, how old, what language?

My take is that it is "The Infinite Worlds of H.G. Wells" (Wikipedia, IMDB)
This miniseries is from 2001, has 3 episodes recounting 2 H.G. Wells stories each. Part of the 1st episode centers on an "Invisible Man", who gained this ability from acceleration, a retelling of "The New Accelerator"
I do not quite recall a hummingbird, but at a point Wells (the protagonist) and prof. Gibberne (an important supporting character) are also accelerated and meet the "Invisible Man" who has grown old in the mean time. 
A synopsis:

The first story "The New Accelerator" reminds considerably of the Star Trek episode Wink of an Eye (1968). This is a good solid science-fiction story. In fact, the original Wells story simply consists of Professor Gibberne (rather than Mark Radcliffe) demonstrating the New Accelerator to the narrator and they observing the effects of time slowed down after taking it. By contrast, the episode sets up a strange mystery – the blast in the lecture hall, the door ripped off its hinges but nothing else affected, the burnt cricket ball impacted through the clocktower, and then brings it together in a dazzling explanation about time being stilled via sped-up metabolism and the problems of built-up momentum. There is a sense of eeriness in the scenes with Tom Ward and Nicholas Rowe walking through a university that has been stilled in motion. Here the mini-series achieves particularly well.


The show may have been The Outer Limits.  Saw it late night here as well, also unrelated episodes.  Here's an episode list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Outer_Limits_(1995_TV_series)_episodes
Good luck!
